# Do not mark emails on the Unread tab as read after changing focus

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook-2013, unread-mail

I have Outlook 2013 on Windows 10 configured such that when I'm on the *All* tab in the Inbox and change which email is in focus (thus, displaying it in the reading pane) Outlook automatically marks the email as Read.

Without changing the above behavior, I want to configure Outlook so that when I'm on the *Unread* tab it **does not mark the message as Read** such that I have to right-click it to mark it as Read.

Is there a way to do this?

I've noted that Outlook Web App does this by default, but I could not find this specific setting on the desktop version of Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

this has always bothered me too. I didn't even think to look for a setting until I saw this but I found one. Go to File, choose Options on the left hand pane, then choose Mail. Under "Outlook panes", click the "Reading Pane..." button. Then check the "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" option and enter the number of seconds you want to wait before marking it read.

Comment: Well, this could be a good solution, but then it applies the setting for the whole inbox, all tabs.I'd like to be able to apply this setting only for the Unread tab.